# (CSS3 flex box) specifying multiple box-lines doesn't work

Tags: css, model

Using flex box, I'm trying to create flexible article nodes that wrap when they fill their parent container (4 or so nodes per row). Currently, they remain on one line and overflow the parent without wrapping. Any ideas?

My css:

```
.container { 
    display: -webkit-box; 
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-lines: multiple;   
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; }

.container article {
       -webkit-box-flex: 1; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been experimenting a bit with flexboxes, but as far I could find out, there is no current browser which implements the "box-lines: multiple" command.

The Apple developer documentation claims that it exists since iOS 1.0 and Safari 3.0, however the status of all the flex-box commands still reads "under development". So the command exists, and is not rejected as an error, but only the "single" value is currently working, as it seems.

Comment: "Under development" means that it's not in W3 standard yet and it's not related to the fact that it's implemented or not.

Answer (score 0):

IE10 will have it implemented when released. The others might be doing so in the future as well.

http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/ie10-future-of-css-layout?blog=2

Here is another post I found about the topic.

http://www.xanthir.com/blog/b48Z0

"*The multiple line support has been marked as at-risk in the new draft, as it appears to require a more extensive treatment than is given to it in this draft.*"

"*A pair of properties, flex-break-before and flex-break-after, can produce explicit line breaks before/after a flexbox child, or prevent linebreaks from ever occuring.*"